# Opportunity Validation Rule on Closed Won Opportunities

Tags: validation, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to get a Validation Rule on my opportunities that only fires when a non-admin tries to Close Win.  However, I'm running into a problem when a non-admin user moves the opportunity to Closed Lost (which I want them to be able to do)

I've tried different variations of the rule below.  I cannot find a separate stage name for Closed, Closed Won, & Closed Lost.

AND (

ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"),

$User.Id <> "005j000000FPcwR")

The Validation Rule should only fire on Closed Won, not Closed Lost

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend updating the $User.Id reference to point to the Profile Id (updating the Id correctly in the process). Then I would wrap the ISPICKVAL with a NOT(). Validation rules evaluate to the error case, not the accepted case.

Replace the Id found being compared to the ProfileId with the appropriate value you need, but I believe this should do what you need:

```
AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won")), $User.ProfileId <> "00e36000001XAnQAAW")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, I want a non-admin user to be able to select all opportunity stages, except Closed Won.  Wouldn't not need the "NOT"?   I have used the User Profile ID which is probably the better route